# Saml for ping in c#

Tags: c#, saml

Currently we are using **ASP.Net** membership for providing authentication in our application. Now our client has moved to ping for user store. So we need to modify our application to support SSO and want us to use Saml.

My question is

1. Other than Saml, is there any other authentication technique I can use for ping?
2. If Saml is the better option can you give me any links.

Comment: start with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: from Ping website `Ping builds solutions on open standards to enable any required use case. PingAccess accepts secure REST and SOAP-based services using SAML, OAuth, OIDC, WS-Fed and WS-Trust...`

Answer (score 0):

Ping supports all the federation standards.

Basically you can use WS-Fed, SAML 2.0 or OpenID Connect.

Whichever protocol you pick, you need a client-side stack that implements it.

The easiest to get working is OpenID Connect.